# Swift Google Maps select marker camera animation bug

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps in my Swift iOS app with custom icons for markers.  Previously, when I select a marker, the camera would smoothly move to the marker with this code:

```
mapView.animate(toLocation: dealershipLocation.coordinate)
```

Now, I've added code that changes the icon of the selected marker when tapped:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    print("debug: did tap \(marker)")

    if let lastMarker = mapView.selectedMarker {
        lastMarker.iconView = nil
        if let markerView = unselectedMarkerView {
            lastMarker.iconView = markerView
        }
    }

    mapView.selectedMarker = marker

    if let curMarker = mapView.selectedMarker {
        curMarker.iconView = nil
        if let markerView = selectedMarkerView {
            curMarker.iconView = markerView
        }
    }

    if let name = marker.title {
        viewModel.selectMarker(name: name)
    }

    return true
}
```

The problem is now the camera animation is no longer always smooth.  About 1/6 or 7 times, the camera will jump before smoothly animating to the selected marker.  It appears to have something to do with this line:

```
mapView.selectedMarker = marker
```

because the issue is not there without it.  I've printed the coordinates of the camera before and after tapping the marker and this is the result:

```
debug: map did change position GMSCameraPosition 0x142754e10: target:(37.945, -87.400) bearing:0.000 zoomLevel:15.000 viewingAngle:0.000
debug: did tap <GMSMarker: 0x134822dc0> CPHT Land Rover (37.949446, -87.404970), <UIImageView: 0x11c620d80; frame = (0 0; 80 80); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x123201ba0>>
debug: did select
debug: map will move not user
debug: map did change position GMSCameraPosition 0x144129650: target:(37.949, -87.405) bearing:0.000 zoomLevel:15.000 viewingAngle:0.000
debug: map did change position GMSCameraPosition 0x144142710: target:(37.945, -87.400) bearing:0.000 zoomLevel:15.000 viewingAngle:0.000
debug: map did change position GMSCameraPosition 0x144162cd0: target:(37.946, -87.401) bearing:0.000 zoomLevel:15.000 viewingAngle:0.000
debug: map did change position GMSCameraPosition 0x144112e10: target:(37.946, -87.401) bearing:0.000 zoomLevel:15.000 viewingAngle:0.000
debug: map did change position GMSCameraPosition 0x144135b90: target:(37.946, -87.401) bearing:0.000 zoomLevel:15.000 viewingAngle:0.000
debug: map did change position GMSCameraPosition 0x1441a0d50: target:(37.947, -87.402) bearing:0.000 zoomLevel:15.000 viewingAngle:0.000
debug: map did change position GMSCameraPosition 0x144157390: target:(37.947, -87.402) bearing:0.000 zoomLevel:15.000 viewingAngle:0.000
```

The debug continues until it reaches the marker. This bug causes the camera to sometimes immediately jump to the selected marker, return to the previous spot, then smoothly move the camera to the selected marker.  If I remove the animate toLocation call, the camera never moves when selecting a marker.  Google Documentation has hardly anything on the selectedMarker property.  Any help would be much appreciated!